# Suggestion for WHERE condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Here's the edited code:  This code is more close to the actual code I am running. It gives me all records except for Cancelled records. I want to include cancelled records with NOT NULL fields in Prod columns.

```
Select  AppID,
    Prod1, 
Prod2, 
Prod3, 
Prod4, 
Prod5, 
Prod6, 
Prod7, 
Prod8,
CASE WHEN len(Prod1) > 0 OR
   len(Prod2) > 0 OR
       len(Prod3) > 0 OR
       len(Prod4) > 0 OR
       len(Prod5) > 0 OR
       len(Prod6) > 0 OR
       len(Prod7) > 0 OR
       len(Prod8) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NbrIncomplete
WHERE      (CASE WHEN LEFT(ProductShortName, 2) IN ('CT', 'GR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0) AND  
       (CTRACKS.Ctrack IS NULL) AND (AppInitiatedDate >= @StartDate) AND (AppInitiatedDate < @EndDate) AND 
       (Status <> N'Cancelled' OR
    Status IS NULL) 
OR
       (CASE WHEN LEFT(ProductShortName, 2) IN ('CT', 'GR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0) AND 
       (CTRACKS.Ctrack IS NULL) AND (Status <> N'Cancelled' OR
        Status IS NULL) AND 
   (CASE WHEN 
         len(Prod1) > 0 OR
             len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                     len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                     len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                     len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                     len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                     len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                     len(Prod1) > 0 
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1)
ORDER BY AppID
```

Comment: What are the data types of the `Prod` columns?, what are the results of your current query?

Comment: WHERE status=cancelled AND Prod1 IS NULL AND Prod2 IS NULL...

Comment: You need IS NOT NULL instead, but that's the point.

Comment: datatypes for prod Columns are nvarchar

Comment: It's very rude here to post images of code rather than the text of the code.

Comment: I agree...But while posting the code, I was getting error and decided to post an image. Apologize for that.

Comment: See my edit for how to do it right.

Comment: `Rude` is a bit harsh, but posting the code and values as text makes it a lot easier for folks to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to run the code successfully and got the desired output. Yeyy!!!

```
Select  AppID, 
Prod1, 
Prod2, 
Prod3, 
Prod4, 
Prod5, 
Prod6, 
Prod7, 
Prod8,
CASE WHEN len(Prod1) > 0 OR
   len(Prod2) > 0 OR
   len(Prod3) > 0 OR
   len(Prod4) > 0 OR
   len(Prod5) > 0 OR
   len(Prod6) > 0 OR
   len(Prod7) > 0 OR
   len(Prod8) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NbrIncomplete
WHERE      
   (CASE WHEN LEFT(ProductShortName, 2) IN ('CT', 'GR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0) AND  
   (CTRACKS.Ctrack IS NULL) AND ((Status = 'Cancelled' AND 
   Prod1 IS NOT NULL OR
   Prod1 IS NOT NULL OR
   Prod1 IS NOT NULL OR
   Prod1 IS NOT NULL OR
   Prod1 IS NOT NULL OR
   Prod1 IS NOT NULL OR
   Prod1 IS NOT NULL OR
   Prod1 IS NOT NULL)) OR Status <> 'Cancelled')
   AND 
   (AppInitiatedDate >= @StartDate) AND (AppInitiatedDate < @EndDate)  
   OR
   (CASE WHEN LEFT(ProductShortName, 2) IN ('CT', 'GR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0) AND 
   (CTRACKS.Ctrack IS NULL) AND 
   (CASE WHEN 
     len(Prod1) > 0 OR
         len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                 len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                 len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                 len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                 len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                 len(Prod1) > 0 OR
                 len(Prod1) > 0 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1)
  ORDER BY AppID
```

Thank you for your efforts. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the sample of your desired output, you want this:

```
SELECT AppID, Status, Prod1,Prod2,Prod3,Prod4,Prod5,Prod6,Prod7,Prod8
FROM   Status
WHERE  Coalesce(Prod1, Prod2, Prod3, Prod4, Prod5, Prod6, Prod7, Prod8) IS NOT NULL
   OR  Status <> 'Cancelled'
```

That assumes a reasonable DB schema, such that the values of the Prod1,etc columns are NULL, and not empty strings. If they are empty strings, you should *fix the schema*.

---

Having just seen your comment that the Prod[n] types are, indeed, `nvarchar`, I will re-iterate: **you should fix the db schema**. What you have is *broken*. In addition to making this query more complicated than it needs to be, it will also be near-impossible to accurately compare dates to find things like, for example, which prod[n] for a specific row came first (I also recommend pulling those product fields out into a separate table, with the key for this table plus product number and date as columns).

But in the near term, and not knowing yet whether the empty values in the report are `NULL` or just empty strings, you can do this:

```
SELECT    AppID, Status, Prod1,Prod2,Prod3,Prod4,Prod5,Prod6,Prod7,Prod8
FROM      Status
WHERE     Status <> 'Cancelled' OR 
           LEN(coalesce(Prod1,''))>0 or
           LEN(coalesce(Prod2,''))>0 or
           LEN(coalesce(Prod3,''))>0 or
           LEN(coalesce(Prod4,''))>0 or
           LEN(coalesce(Prod5,''))>0 or
           LEN(coalesce(Prod6,''))>0 or
           LEN(coalesce(Prod7,''))>0 or
           LEN(coalesce(Prod8,''))>0  
ORDER BY   AppID
```

I provide that because you likely have someone who needs this data **now**, but again: *your very next task* should be to fix the schema to use `date` types.

Comment: Don't think this will work.  It will exclude rows with statuses other than `Cancelled` where all the dates are null.  Like row 105.

Comment: @Andrew I had misread the sample. It's fixed now. It will allow both rows 105 and 102 now.

Comment: Ooh, nice catch on the data type. I missed that.

Comment: Thank you Joel for your time to answer my query. I have edited the query to give little more clear understanding of what I want. Could you please suggest the query to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

That where clause isn't going to work like you want it to.  You need something like this:

```
where
(status = 'CANCELLED' and (PROD1 is not null or prod2 is not null<etc>))
or
status <> 'CANCELLED'
```

Here's a simplified example:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93187/6)

Comment: thank you all for the answers. I tried rewriting the query given by @Andrew and Joel Coehoorn but it still won't wotk. The query is more complicated than the example query I posted. Here is the 'close to real query' I am working on. It gives all the records except for Cancelled records. But I want to Include 'Cancelled' records with 'NOT NULL'. Please look at the edited version of my question. Thanks again for your wonderful efforts. Appreciate it.

Comment: Can someone please help, I am trying to paste the edited code here. But unable to do it. I even tried editing in my Question, but still gving me the same error.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I was able to rewrite the query to little close to the real query. With some additional conditions. I tried running the code given by you but its not giving the desired output. Would you be able to suggest a code based on the edited code?

Answer (score 0):

`IS NOT NULL` instead of `>0`
So: `WHERE Status <> 'Cancelled' AND (Prod1 IS NOT NULL or Prod2 IS NOT NULL or Prod3 IS NOT NULL or Prod4 IS NOT NULL or Prod5 IS NOT NULL or Prod6 IS NOT NULL or Prod7 IS NOT NULL or Prod8 IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from status 
    where (Status<>'Cancelled' and Prod1 is not null and...and Prod8 is not null) or Status='Cancelled'
```